# MongoDB Array query,I got a bad performance

Tags: performance, mongodb

the taglist field is array data type,and scorea is a int type:
the follow is my performance test:

```
     condition                                                                              qps
     * 1.collection.find().limit(1000).sort(new BasicDBObject("scorea",1))            420
     * 2.dbObj.put("taglist",new BasicDBObject().append("$in",Array("女士","男士")))
     *   val res = collection.find(dbObj).limit(1000)                                 200
     * 3.dbObj.put("taglist",new BasicDBObject().append("$all",Array("女士","男士"))
     *   val res = collection.find(dbObj).limit(1000)                                 200
     * 4.dbObj.put("taglist",new BasicDBObject().append("$all",Array("女士","男士"))
     *   val res = collection.find(dbObj).limit(1000)                                 50
```

420, 200, 50 is the qps count,the performance is bad how can I get a better performance?

ps: I already created a index on field taglist and scorea.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do would be to see if your query is using the index by appending .explain() to your query.

The reference documentation can be found here http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/

If not then it's trying to understand why not. If it is then it looks like further tuning or an alternative index(es) is required.